openSUSE Tumbleweed won't hibernate, LVM on LUKS FDE but everything configured OK
My openSUSE Tumbleweed should hibernate but won't and I do not understand why.  I have had similar systems (Arch Linux) hibernate under the same circumstances.  Here is my config:

EFI-GRUB boot
LVM on LUKS; LVM has root, home and swap partitions
Swap enabled and mounted by UUID in /etc/fstab, swapon -s shows it being active.  It is 32GB in size with 16GB RAM installed.
GRUB has resume statements in the default config and /boot/grub2/grub.cfg (see below).

Here are a few commands to check hibernation capabilities of kernel and system:
# zgrep HIBERN /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_ARCH_HIBERNATION_POSSIBLE=y
CONFIG_ARCH_HIBERNATION_HEADER=y
CONFIG_HIBERNATE_CALLBACKS=y
CONFIG_HIBERNATION=y
CONFIG_HIBERNATION_SNAPSHOT_DEV=y
CONFIG_HIBERNATION_COMP_LZO=y
# CONFIG_HIBERNATION_COMP_LZ4 is not set
CONFIG_HIBERNATION_DEF_COMP="lzo"

So the kernel is configured to support hibernation.
This boot (by GRUB) has:
# cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.11.6-2-default root=/dev/mapper/cryptolvm-opensuse splash=silent resume=/dev/mapper/cryptolvm-swap mem_sleep_default=deep security=selinux selinux=1 enforcing=1 mitigations=auto

I tried varying resume= using UUID=.... with the swap's UUID with no effect.
# cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem

Here disk is missing but I do not know why.
Of course this will not work now:
# systemctl hibernate
Call to Hibernate failed: Sleep verb 'hibernate' is not configured or configuration is not supported by kernel
Exit 1

Does the kernel depend on the BIOS to enable hibernation?  (Not to my knowledge.)  In this case, can I check something there?


Your swap space must be contiguous, check with filefrag. 2. To resume, your swap space must be available very early in the boot process, probably before the "LVM on LUKS" is available; rearrange your swap to be on a real partition.


@waltinator Thanks. The swap is on a formatted swap partition which means it is contiguous. The swap partition is available at the same time as the / partition (where grub.cfg lies and points to the swap partition) and that ought to be early enough? I have had an Arch Linux system hibernate from such a setup before. Unencrypted swap should not be used for hibernation if there is a possibility that an attacker (or someone finding the device once lost) can access it.
